# Images in django not showing up in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

This is an application in which I'm using django backend and react frontend. The images display in react when I keep react and django
separate and communicate simply with the APIs. However, I want to deploy both the frontend and backend together.
I'm trying to use django `re_path` to redirect any url that does't match with the urls specifiled in django `urls.py`. Whenever I do
this the images from react and django stop displaying. Both django and react lose track of the path of the images.

```
project structure
>backend
    ...
    settings.py
    urls.py
>blog
    ...
    urls.py
    serializers.py
    views.py
>frontend
    ...
    build
    src
    package.json
manage.py
>static
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('api/', include('djoser.urls.jwt')),
    path('api/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('summernote/',include('django_summernote.urls')),
    path('api/blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    re_path('*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
   
]
```

settings.py

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/build')
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
    },
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static',),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'frontend/build/static'),
    ]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

How do I fix this? I'm using Django v4

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it using path instead of re_path. I had to change `re_path('*', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))` to re_path('', `TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))`. I don't know if changes regarding the use of repath in Django 4.0

Answer (score 0):

> If the paths and converters syntax isn’t sufficient for defining your URL patterns, you can also use regular expressions. To do so, use re_path() instead of path().

So you cannot write "*"
In my case
`re_path(r'^(?P<path>.*)$'...)`
will match any path

By The way. If you use django-react. you cannot use re_path for front-end Template. Example:

```bash
re_path(r'^(?P<path>.*)$',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html')),
```

Doing so will lead to corsheader error when loading Images

Answer (score 0):

if your images are showing on backend and not frontend
try this in react code:

```
<img className="" src={`http://127.0.0.1:8000/${item.image}`} />
```

where http://127.0.0.1:8000 is the url of backend
use backticks with whole src